# Compound Poisson random variable

Tags: random-variable, covariance, poisson-process, compound-distributions

A compound Poisson random variable $S$ is defined as:
$S=\displaystyle\sum^N_{i=1}X_i,$ 
where $N$ is a random draw from a Poisson distribution with intensity parameter $\lambda$, and $X_i$ are independent identically distributed random variables.

What is $\operatorname{Cov}(S,N)$?

$N$ is a Poisson random variable with mean $\lambda $. $S$ is compound Poisson random variable with Poisson parameter $\lambda $ and component distribution $F$.

$X_i$  where i =1,2,...is a sequence of iid r. v.s having distribution $F$

Comment: What is  N? You are interested in covariance with the number of variables?

Comment: I edited the question to make it self-contained. I think it's an interesting question. I don't recall seeing and answer to it before.

Comment: You cannot answer the question without defining the distribution of the $X_i$'s.

Comment: dxaston has already answered this question correctly. So Now no matter, if it is deleted or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We'll denote $\mu_N = \text{E}(N)$, $\mu_X = \text{E}(X)$ and $\sigma_N^2 = \text{Var}(N)$.  To find the covariance we can use the formula

\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(S, N) &= \text{E}(SN) - \text{E}(S) \text{E}(N) \\
&= \text{E}(SN) - \mu_N^2 \mu_X 
\end{align}

where the second equality is found by taking an iterated expectation

\begin{align}
\text{E}(S) &= \text{E} [ \text{E}(S \mid N) ] \\
&= \text{E} \left [ \text{E} \left (\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i \mid N \right ) \right ] \\
&= \text{E} [ N \text{E}(X) ] \\
&= \mu_N \mu_X .
\end{align}

To find $\text{E}(SN)$ we make a similar conditioning argument

\begin{align}
\text{E}(SN) &= \text{E} \left [ \text{E}(SN \mid N) \right ] \\
&= \text{E} \left [ N^2 \text{E}(X) \right ] \\
&= \mu_X \left ( \sigma_N^2 + \mu_N^2 \right )
\end{align}

and so we get

\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(S, N) &= \mu_X \sigma_N^2 .
\end{align}

Comment: But E(S)=$\lambda$E(X)

Comment: @Dhamnekar Yes, that's what I have.  $\lambda = \mu_N$ when $N \sim$ Poisson$(\lambda)$.  I gave the general solution where $N$ need not be Poisson distributed.